# Selecting object from ArrayList associated with minimum value attribute Android

Tags: android, google-maps, arraylist

I am trying to calculate distance between a location(source location marker) to the other locations stored in an ArrayList(returned from RoutesData) and storing the locations along the distances in another ArrayList and then selecting the LatLng with minimum distance .My code for the particular logic is.

**Class RoutesData :** returns the LatLngs to measure distance

```
public class RoutesData {

    public ArrayList<LatLng> allRoutesMainStops(){
        ArrayList<LatLng> allPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>(Arrays.asList(
                //icPoints
                new LatLng(33.582752, 73.044503),new LatLng(33.595504, 73.050912),
                //station
                new LatLng(33.601097, 73.047798),new LatLng(33.598755, 73.055607),new LatLng(33.599970, 73.063225),new LatLng(33.602757, 73.066996),new LatLng(33.604297, 73.075843),new LatLng(33.608692, 73.082024),
                //ali nawaz
                new LatLng(33.617330, 73.081743),
                //centre hosp
                new LatLng(33.630072, 73.071996),new LatLng(33.631454, 73.072416),new LatLng(33.633905, 73.062379),new LatLng(33.641462, 73.063376),new LatLng(33.646714, 73.064095),new LatLng(33.651782, 73.064535),new LatLng(33.661329, 73.063974),new LatLng(33.672490, 73.055906),new LatLng(33.683642, 73.047215),new LatLng(33.689706, 73.030363),new LatLng(33.680982, 73.018654),new LatLng(33.671293, 73.016894),
                //gpo 1
                new LatLng(33.595215, 73.051496),new LatLng(33.593119, 73.054184),new LatLng(33.585280, 73.066763),new LatLng(33.588925, 73.076172),new LatLng(33.599117, 73.080001),new LatLng(33.607101, 73.083641),new LatLng(33.626583, 73.075027),
                //new LatLng(33.630072, 73.071996), //duplicate center
                new LatLng(33.631550, 73.072534),new LatLng(33.639063, 73.075742),new LatLng(33.643424, 73.077372),new LatLng(33.650480, 73.080152),new LatLng(33.663188, 73.085446),new LatLng(33.696970, 73.062966),new LatLng(33.699527, 73.073920),new LatLng(33.704257, 73.082993),new LatLng(33.707380, 73.088906),new LatLng(33.717143, 73.082961), new LatLng(33.718617, 73.084589), new LatLng(33.720660, 73.083891), new LatLng(33.727328, 73.073823), new LatLng(33.720397, 73.058392), new LatLng(33.733174, 73.087104)

                ));
        return allPoints;
    }

}
```

**Class LocationDistances:** binds location with distance.

```
public class LocationDistances {
    LatLng locs;
    double distances;
}
```

**getOverAllRoute() method in MainActivity**: which compares source Location with all the LatLngs returned from RouteData Class and Store them in a list srcLocDisList . All the trouble I am facing is in the Second loop which is calculating minimum distance and then returns the object associated with minimum distance but after one iteration the application crashes and while debugging it gives error "Source not found."?

```
public void getOverAllRoute(){
        //to get main route points to measure distance from
        RoutesData rD = new RoutesData();
        ArrayList<LatLng> mainRoutePoints = rD.allRoutesMainStops();
        //Toast.makeText(this,"Size: "+mainRoutePoints.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //to store location + distances from source

        ArrayList<LocationDistances> srcLocDisList = new ArrayList();
        //showMarkerslongLat();
        //create source Location
        Location srcLoc = new Location("");
        srcLoc.setLatitude(sll.latitude);
        srcLoc.setLongitude(sll.longitude);

        // to compare distances from source location
        Location mainPointsLoc = new Location("");
        for(int i =0;i<mainRoutePoints.size();i++){
            LocationDistances srcLocDis = new LocationDistances();
            mainPointsLoc.setLatitude(mainRoutePoints.get(i).latitude);
            mainPointsLoc.setLongitude(mainRoutePoints.get(i).longitude);
            //store distances and location in arraylist
            srcLocDis.locs = mainRoutePoints.get(i);
            srcLocDis.distances = srcLoc.distanceTo(mainPointsLoc);



            srcLocDisList.add(srcLocDis);
            Log.d("Location data: ",srcLocDis.locs.toString());
            Log.d("Saved Data: ",srcLocDisList.get(i).toString());

        }
        //Toast.makeText(this,"items1: "+srcLocDisList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        LocationDistances min=null;
        for(LocationDistances x:srcLocDisList){
            String srcLocDisLocFile = x.locs.latitude+" "+x.locs.longitude+" distances:"+x.distances;


            min=(min==null||x.distances<min.distances)?x:min;
            Log.d("LocDist:",Double.toString(x.distances));

        }
        LatLng srcStartMin=min.locs;
        Toast.makeText(this,srcStartMin.latitude+" "+srcStartMin.longitude+" Distance"+Double.toString(min.distances), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

[Log file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j24rh7u0s5hfn7k/log.txt?dl=0)

Inside Second Loop:[image]

After the first Iterration:
[image]

Comment: Can you please post your code for second loop and LogCat message

Comment: @dora I've editted the question. along log files

Comment: post the logcat please

Comment: @HeshanSandeepa log is at the end of the question

Comment: @dora the loop is supposed to initialize min with the minimum distance while debugging when it enters the loop the min is initilized

Comment: @FaisalNaseer what is the exception you get ?

Comment: @dora I have updated teh question with 2 images what actually happens it compares the first value in the List correctly and add it to minimum but after wards app a screen comes up. and informing source not found

Comment: @FaisalNaseer I can't see any logcat exception messages. Run the app without debugging and post the exception . Clear the search at the top of  the log cat.

Comment: updated log file https://www.dropbox.com/s/j24rh7u0s5hfn7k/log.txt?dl=0

Comment: I think the error is not there in the code you have shared. can you please check the code at line number 560 . I think you are referrring to a string resource that is not there.

Comment: Maybe you got this error message when you tried to use TextView.setText passing a char instead of a String. This makes sense since the char would be promoted to an int which meant that you was really calling the                           -  TextView.setText( int resId );                                                                         -  And since there wasn't a resource with that value, it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should move the below line of code

```
LocationDistances srcLocDis = new LocationDistances();
```

into the for loop like below, otherwise the same object is being overwritten for the rest of the loop

```
for(int i =0;i<mainRoutePoints.size();i++){
        srcLocDis = new LocationDistances();
        mainPointsLoc.setLatitude(mainRoutePoints.get(i).latitude);
        mainPointsLoc.setLongitude(mainRoutePoints.get(i).longitude);
        //store distances and location in arraylist
        srcLocDis.locs = mainRoutePoints.get(i);
        srcLocDis.distances = srcLoc.distanceTo(mainPointsLoc);



        srcLocDisList.add(srcLocDis);
        Log.d("Location data: ",srcLocDis.locs.toString());
        Log.d("Saved Data: ",srcLocDisList.get(i).toString());

    }
```